# PHP - get local array of returned json

Tags: php, arrays

I have a `json` request that returns an array .

```
$json = $api->get(100);
```

This returns an array that i can do for each loop etc on it. However in case I don't have internet connection , I want to save a sample of the array that I instantiate into a variable.

**basically :**

```
$offline_array = array(......);
```

---

In what way can i copy-paste the json array in my browser and then use it to instantiate the array ?

**I tried :**

```
var_dump($x);
print_r($x);
```

Keep getting syntax errors :

```
    $offline = Array ( 
            [99] => Array ( 
                    [id] => 238142 
                    [price1] => 10100.00 
                    [price2] => 10107.00 
                    [created_at] => 2018-02-24 09:27:02 
                    [updated_at] => 2018-02-24 09:27:02 
            ) 
            [98] => Array ( 
                    [id] => 238143 
                    [price1] => 10074.00 
                    [price2] => 10107.00 
                    [created_at] => 2018-02-24 09:28:01 
                    [updated_at] => 2018-02-24 09:28:01 
                    ) 
            [97] => Array ( 
                    [id] => 238144 
                    [price1] => 10084.03 
                    [price2] => 10107.00 
                    [created_at] => 2018-02-24 09:29:02 
                    [updated_at] => 2018-02-24 09:29:02 
                    ) 
             . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) to get the literal representation of the variable, after [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)ing the API result with the `true` parameter to get an array:

```
<?php
$json = '{"test": 123}';
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
echo var_export($arr);
```

*Result:*

> array ( 'test' => 123, )

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/kOAe8)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could store your json in a file and then read it from that file.

For example:

If you are allowed to use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), what you could do is read the file and then use use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```
$json = file_get_contents("file.json");
$offline_array = json_decode($json, true);
```

Use `true` as the second parameter for `json_decode` to return  associative arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var_export()` for this

> [var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) — Outputs or returns a parsable string representation of a variable

Example code, saving the output of the `var_export()` to a file for later use.

```
<?php
$offline = [
        ['id' => 238142,
         'price1' => 10100.00,
         'price2' => 10107.00,
         'created_at' => '2018-02-24 09:27:02',
         'updated_at' => '2018-02-24 09:27:02',
        ],
        ['id' => 238143,
         'price1' => 10074.00,
         'price2' => 10107.00,
         'created_at' => '2018-02-24 09:28:01',
         'updated_at' => '2018-02-24 09:28:01',
         ]
];

$save = var_export($offline);

file_put_contents('offline.txt', $save);

$new = file_get_contents('offline.txt');
print_r($new);
```

Output from `print_r()`

```
array (
  0 =>
  array (
    'id' => 238142,
    'price1' => 10100.0,
    'price2' => 10107.0,
    'created_at' => '2018-02-24 09:27:02',
    'updated_at' => '2018-02-24 09:27:02',
  ),
  1 =>
  array (
    'id' => 238143,
    'price1' => 10074.0,
    'price2' => 10107.0,
    'created_at' => '2018-02-24 09:28:01',
    'updated_at' => '2018-02-24 09:28:01',
  ),
)
```